# Change url-structure for wordpress pages - pages in strucutre not top-level

Tags: posts

I use wordpress as a cms in which i use a some wordpress pages for standard content and posts for a wordpress blog. Now ive got a problem that the pages should not always be on the top level url and that i can set the url of these pages according to the menu i build. I got a page "service" and inside these navigation-branch there are more pages containing explicit services:

Services

- Service 1 (url should be: /services/service1)
- Service 2 (url should be: /services/service2)
- Service 3 (url should be: /services/service3)

How can i do that in wordpress? Best solution would be just if wordpress would use the structure from my wordpress menu.

Thanks four your help and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best solution would be just if wordpress would use the structure from
>   my wordpress menu.

The system doesn't work that way. Menus structure and URL structure are not tied together. You could probably alter permalinks such that this would be the case but it would be a complicated project and potentially cause substantial strain on server resources.

The simplest thing to do is to create nested pages via the backend.

1. Create a page called "Services"
2. Then create all of the other pages as children of that "Services"
   page.

The URL structure would by default be like that you describe (assuming that pretty permalinks are enabled and working). Make your menu match.